# What is the purpose of inductance in PI impedance matching?

Tags: esp8266, impedance-matching

I am designing Wifi RF circuit with ESP8285 and need impedance matching to be done for 39+j6 Ω.

As per suggested PI matching circuit in the datasheet

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEf6zt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am not sure how inductor of 2.2nH would fit this circuit as its going to produce highest resistance for RF signal of 2.45GHz and ideally would block all RF signal captured by antena. Can someone help understand if I am wrong about it and then how would this circuit help capturing the RF signal, can someone suggest what should be selection criteria for inductor and capacitors for impedance matching.

Comment: Link ref doc and show impedance on either side in schema.

Comment: *its going to produce highest resistance for RF signal of 2.45GHz and ideally would block all RF signal captured by antena* 1) calculate the impedance of that inductor at 2.45 GHz and 2) compare that number to the **characteristic impedance** of the system. 3) Realize that (almost) **no power is lost in the inductor** as it is a **reactive** component. The same applies to the capacitors.

Comment: 4) Maybe you should study the subjects of RF, characteristic impedances and impedance matching? This looks like a good starting point: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/radio-frequency-analysis-design/#selected-topics there's also a specific chapter on impedance matching:  https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/radio-frequency-analysis-design/selected-topics/understanding-matching-networks/

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/communications/article/21801154/back-to-basics-impedance-matching-part-3) (and the linked part 2 as well).

In short, for a certain frequency, the Pi network works as a transformer. It can be tuned to match between any combination of source and load impedance.

That's how a great deal of antenna matching circuits look like.

This particular circuit is tuned to ~3GHz, but the exact properties (input and output impedance) can be calculated if one knows the parameters of both the antenna and the ESP8252 chip.